# Prophets dua for dying at a good age

Tags: hadith, source-identification, dua

I heard that prophet SAW used to pray a supplication for dying at a good age, and not being too old. does anyone have the source of this?

Comment: I don't think Prophet of Islam used to supplicate for dying at any good age... The closest you can get is [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/10) Hadith...

Answer (score 1):

So i was looking for this hadith.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) used to seek refuge with Allah saying, "O Allah!
> I seek refuge with You from laziness, and seek refuge with You from
> cowardice, and seek refuge with You from **geriatric old age**, and seek
> refuge with You from miserliness."

Reference    : [Sahih al-Bukhari 6371](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/68)
In-book reference    : Book 80, Hadith 68
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 8, Book 75, Hadith 382
(deprecated numbering scheme)